# Blazor Web API Response handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor app that consume ASP.Net Core Web API using HttpClient.
Here is how the calling service looks like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
{
      return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<TEntity[]>(APIUrl);
}

public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
{
      return await httpClient.PostJsonAsync<TEntity>(APIUrl, entity);
}
```

And the Web API looks like

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await repository.GetAllAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,ex);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> Post(TEntity entity)
    {
         try
         {
            var result = await repository.AddAsync(entity);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), result.Id, result);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
         }
     }
```

Now, if the Web API throws an exception, or if there is Authorization error. How do I handle it in my calling Service and show user the error message.

Comment: What is the type of the HTTP client and in which namespace it resides. Provide sample of code calling AddAsync() method

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13052 it will throw exceptions if anything other than 200 happens.

Comment: It resides in System.Net.Http

Comment: The implementation of AddAsync should not matter, because it will change with different types. But if in a case it throws and exception. I would like to set code to handle it.